# How can I turn multiple spaces into paragraphs in Excel or CSV file?

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

I have an Excel/CSV that was exported from an ASP website and I need to import the data into Wordpress/MySQL.  I am having a problem with the biography field since in the Excel cell it has spaces between the paragraphs but when I import them it doesn't.  It would work if I could insert two:
    `<br><br>` 
instead of the three or four spaces but I'm not sure how to do this.

Each of the 4,000 biography cells has 2 to 5 paragraphs for example

Don graduated from the University of Southern California (USC) with a Bachelor of Science Degree in Real Estate Finance in 1979. While attending college, he worked part-time for Banker, known etc.

Upon graduation from USC in June of 1979, Don accepted a brokerage position with the real estate brokerage firm of Wakefield of California. Don became part of the firm's Industrial / Technology Group. The combination of his college major and etc.

(there are 3 maybe 4 spaces between each paragraph but no html code)

Comment: Did you try to replace the "   " (three spaces) with "<br>"?

Comment: I can do it for 1 cell but there are 4,000 and I don't know how to write a formula that replaces multiple spaces, any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use any formula. Just use the 'Find and Replace' functionality using Ctrl+H.

Then just substitute three spaces with 
:
[image]